# Estimating the length of a curve given individual points

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am trying to estimate the length of a curve given individual points.

The points on the curve are $(1,7), (2,3.29), (3,1.28), (4, 0.29), (5,0), (6, 0.29), (7, 1.28), (8, 3.29), (9,7)$

This problem appears in my calculus textbook, specifically in the section under integrals. I'm not seeing how this can be estimated with an integral. I plotted the points to see the curve, but it is not a quadratic equation.

I'm looking for ways to estimate the length of this curve using calculus. The only way I can currently think of is to sum the distances between each point.

Comment: Summing the straight line distances between each point will give you a lower bound on the arc length. Without some restrictions on the type of curve you're looking at it's not possible to do much better than that, since the true arc length could be arbitrarily large. For example, the true curve could have a tall narrow spike passing through (1.5, 1000).

Comment: The problem is set in the real world, specifically students looking at a chain on a wall where the x-coordinate is the length along the wall and y-coordinate is height above the floor. Does this provide any restriction on the curve?

Comment: The curve formed by a chain hanging freely from its ends is a [catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary). For the points you've listed its equation should be of the form
$$
y=a\left(\cosh\left(\frac{x-5}{a}\right)-1\right)\ ,
$$
and you'd have to choose the parameter $\ a\ $ to give the best fit for the curve to your data.